# Nested structure handling from unmanaged cpp to managed c# using IntPtr

Tags: c#, c++, struct, intptr

I am trying to assign the values to the structure array in managed c# and accessing the same in the cpp.

Consider the following structures in cpp:

```
struct NSCASR_RCG_ITEM_ST
{
    char* pstrSlotName;
    char* pstrReportedText;
    short usConfidence;
    unsigned long ulLocation;
    unsigned long ulDuration;
};

struct NSCASR_RCG_PHRASE_ST
{
    unsigned short usConfidence;
    unsigned short usNumItems;
    short sGrammarIndex;
    short sGrammarType;
    NSCASR_RCG_ITEM_ST Item[1];
};     

struct NSCASR_RCG_RES_ST
{
    unsigned long ulSizeBytes;
    unsigned long ulWarnings;
    unsigned short usNumPhrases;
    char*  pstrWaveformURI;
    unsigned long ulWaveformSizeBytes;
    unsigned long ulWaveformDuration;
    NSCASR_RCG_PHRASE_ST * pPhrase[1];
};
```

Consider the following structures in c#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit,CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct NSCASR_RCG_ITEM_ST
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public IntPtr pstrSlotName;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public IntPtr pstrReportedText;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public ushort usConfidence;
    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public uint ulLocation;
    [FieldOffset(14)]
    public uint ulDuration;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct NSCASR_RCG_PHRASE_ST
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ushort usConfidence;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public ushort usNumItems;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public short sGrammarIndex;
    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public short sGrammarType;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public IntPtr Item;/*This holds pointer to NSCASR_RCG_ITEM_ST*/
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct NSCASR_RCG_RES_ST
{

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint ulSizeBytes;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public uint ulWarnings;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public ushort usNumPhrases;
    [FieldOffset(12)]
    public IntPtr pstrWaveformURI;
    [FieldOffset(16)]
    public uint ulWaveformSizeBytes;
    [FieldOffset(20)]
    public uint ulWaveformDuration;
    [FieldOffset(24)]
    public IntPtr pPhrase;/*This holds pointer to NSCASR_RCG_PHRASE_ST*/
}
```

Using the above structures, I am assigning values to NSCASR_RCG_ITEM_ST structure members as follows :

```
public unsafe static int ASR_Recognize_ResultsGet(ref Constants.NSCASR_RCG_RES_ST pRecognitionResults)
{
    Constants.NSCASR_RCG_PHRASE_ST[] test = new Constants.NSCASR_RCG_PHRASE_ST[1];
    Constants.NSCASR_RCG_ITEM_ST[] itm = new Constants.NSCASR_RCG_ITEM_ST[1];
    itm[0].pstrSlotName = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("123");
    itm[0].pstrReportedText = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("456");
    itm[0].usConfidence = 789;
    itm[0].ulLocation = 888;
    itm[0].ulDuration = 999;

    GCHandle arrHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(test, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    GCHandle itmhandle = GCHandle.Alloc(itm, GCHandleType.Pinned);

    try
    {
        test[0].Item = itmhandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        pRecognitionResults.pPhrase = arrHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        arrHandle.Free();
        itmhandle.Free();
    }
}
```

But I am unable to access the data in cpp.
Following is the cpp code where i am accessing the members

```
NSCASR_RCG_RES_ST phrase[2] = { 0 };
int _tmain()
{
    int *result;

    NSCASR_RCG_PHRASE_ST * ptr1;
    NSCASR_RCG_RES_ST *rec = (NSCASR_RCG_RES_ST *)phrase;
    NSCASR_RCG_ITEM_ST item[1];

    ASR_Recognize_ResultsGet(rec);

    ptr1 = rec->pPhrase[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d--%s", i, ptr1[i].Item[i].pstrSlotName);
        printf("\n%d--%s", i, ptr1[i].Item[i].pstrReportedText);
        printf("\n%d--%d", i, ptr1[i].Item[i].usConfidence);
        printf("\n%d--%d", i, ptr1[i].Item[i].ulLocation);
        printf("\n%d--%d", i, ptr1[i].Item[i].ulDuration);
        printf("\n%d--%d", i, ptr1[i].Item[i].usConfidence);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The last members of these two structs are not IntPtr, they are [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)].  A fair headache in native C++ as well, you have to malloc() the storage for the struct and make it large enough to fit the array, casting the pointer to the structure type.  And a headache in C#, having to write Marshal.AllocHGlobal() code is very little joy.  One trick you can use is omit the array from the structure so you can at least use Marshal.StructureToPtr() for the other members.  Another one is to just make the array as large as you ever need.

Comment: When I use the  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)],  Access violation reading location 0x00000004 is obtained . The only solution where I can get the address of cpp is using IntPtr so  I used the Intptr for structure array.